# Incorrect Syntax; Access VBA function to SQL Server

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am converting a large MS Access application to run almost entirely on SQL Server to increase performance as the Access DB is ancient and extremely slow. As such I am working on recreating the VBA functions into SQL functions. SQL Server is giving me syntax errors all over the place and I am trying to understand why, here is the VBA:

```
Function AlphaNum(prodno As String)
Dim i As Long
If Len(prodno) = 0 Then Exit Function
For i = 1 To Len(prodno)
    If Mid(prodno, i, 1) Like "[0-9a-z]" Then AlphaNum = AlphaNum & Mid(prodno, i, 1)
Next i
If IsNumeric(AlphaNum) Then
    While Left(AlphaNum, 1) = "0"
        AlphaNum = Mid(AlphaNum, 2)
    Wend
End If
End Function
```

I've gotten this far with SQL.. I am certainly not an expert at this either, any ideas?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[NAL_AlphaNum]
( 
@prodno varchar(10)
)
RETURNS VarChar(10)

BEGIN
    DECLARE @counter INT,
            @AlphaNum varchar(10)
    SET @counter='1'

    CASE WHEN Len(@prodno) = 0 THEN EXIT 

    WHILE @counter < Len(@prodno)
    BEGIN
        CASE WHEN Mid(@prodno, i, 1) LIKE '[0-9a-z]'
        THEN @AlphaNum =  @AlphaNum + Mid(@prodno, i, 1)
   SET @counter = @counter + 1
        END

    CASE WHEN IsNumeric(@AlphaNum) THEN
        WHILE Left(@AlphaNum, 1) = '0'
            @AlphaNum = Mid(@AlphaNum, 2)
            END

    RETURN @AlphaNum
END;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This needs a bit more thought behind it.  First, figure out what the function does.  See if it's a critical aspect that has to survive.  If it does, figure out what it does, and research alternatives; SQL Server is great, but it's not meant to do everything Access does.  If you're keeping the Access frontend on top of SQL Server, it should stay there, not moved.

Comment: If this is the case is there any way to pass access functions to SQL via pass-through queries?

Comment: Nope.  You need to rethink your approach.  Apply some requirements to this project; why does this function need to make it over?  What is the future state?  Will the front end change?  Not everything should be in the database, and this seems like a prime candidate to exclude.